# DOMDocument select only outer elements

Tags: php, domdocument

If I got a `DOMDocument` like this:

```
<div name="outer">
    <div name="inner"></div>
    <div name="inner"></div>
</div>
<div name="outer">
</div>
<div name="outer">
    <div name="inner"></div>
</div>
```

If I do `$dom->getElementsByTagName('div')`, I am going to get all 6 elements, including the inner ones.

How can I for example select the second outer div element? (`name` is just to show what I mean, the elements don't have these propertys for real!)

**Edit:**

I know I could use `xpath`, but I am more likely looking for a solution without it as I am using only the DOMDocument functions in the rest of my code.

Comment: every dom node has 'context' of where it is in the tree, includin what it's ancestors are. get all divs, see if there's a div in the ancestors. if there aren't, then it's an "outer" div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$entry = $xpath->query('/div[2]');
```